# I just cant add cl to path

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, msvc12

I will be brief with the problem I am facing,
I am a new c++ learner and I opted to work with Vs Code and Msvc. I successfully managed to get vs code. then I installed visual studio 2022. I realised there is still no cl in the path. so Installed build tools next:-
[image]

the problem still exists, I just cant make cl to the path, even vcvars.bat or vcvars64 or any version of vcvars doesn't work, adding bin folders to the path doesn't work aswell. can someone guide me how I can successfully install the compiler?

Edit-1:
running build task in  vscode gives
[image]

Comment: Why not use MSVS?  Instead of making things harder for yourself.

Comment: You would find things a lot easier if you just uninstall VSCode and used MSVC on its own. VSCode is a text editor, MSVC is the compiler.

Comment: that for sure is my last option but I am kinda used to with vs code also the tutorials I watch use the same, msvs just seems a bit more complicated rn

Comment: If you have got yourself in a fix, then the thing to do is to uninstall everything and start again (this time without VSCode). I've always found install Visual Studio extremely easy, so I have no idea what you have done wrong. But starting again, instead of trying to fix a broken installation is the smart thing to do.

Comment: unfortunately i alsready uninstalled everthing and tried

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean by 'no cl in the path'. What exactly are you doing, and what error message do you see?

Comment: It might be faster to simply install Linux, with a modern C++ compiler and a choice of editors included in all major distributions, no need to try to install a bunch of stuff separately and stitch together multiple moving targets.

Comment: Setting up VSCode is actually quite difficult, setting it up to work with MSVC is more difficult than most (because it's not something that many people try to do).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Installing Visual Studio alone is extremely simple, but the OP has chosen a more complex option.

Comment: i just installed vscode and build tools (msvc as a compiler). all I want it the vscode to run build task successfully

Comment: @muzaafnameerfirdausi How do you start VSCode? Please give more details of exactly what you do. Believe it or not the more detail you give the easier it is to help you.

Comment: i installed vscode, then i opened it, created a new folder, created main.cpp and then tried to build it. i cld have opted for GCC but Msvc is supposedly better option. after running the build task I got this error

Comment: 'I opened it', that was the mistake.

Comment: @muzaafnameerfirdausi This is how you start VSCode when you are using MSVC. 1. Open the Visual Studio Console (using vcvars.bat or whatever). 2. cd to the folder containing your project. 3. Type the command `code .`. (that's code space dot). 4. Then build.

Comment: doing these steps result in the same thing

Comment: What happens if you just type `cl` from the visual studio console?

Comment: cl : The term 'cl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the   
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ cl
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cl:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: You are in powershell. That might work (I'm not sure). Try again with the regular visual studio console.

Comment: From the start menu - Visual Studio 2022/Developer command prompt for VS 2022

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc)?

Comment: @muzaafnameerfirdausi If you get into the visual studio console and you get an error like that from the command `cl` then your installation of Visual Studio is faulty, and you should reinstall (I have no idea what the problem would be though I've always found visual studio installations to be very straghtforward). At least now you know the proper way to start VSCode, so maybe once the other problem is fixed you might get something working.

Comment: @AlanBirtles working as per the documentation works. WOW ITS BUILDING IT

Comment: @john okay i wd try to do that again

Comment: @muzaafnameerfirdausi The documentation is only telling you what I tried to tell you.

Comment: yeah the main problem was the vs code's default task.json is bad and the one from documentation I just pasted it